# S3 Access Denied

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, policies

Since yesterday, I've been getting an Access Denied error when I'm trying to upload a file to one of my S3 buckets.

Javascript code:

```js
var pass = new stream.PassThrough();

var contentType = (input.fileName.endsWith('.html') ? 'text/html' : 'text/javascript');

var params = {
  Bucket: 'BUCKET_NAME',
  Key: input.fileName,
  Body: pass,
  ACL: 'public-read',
  ContentType: contentType
};

S3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error while uploading file: ' + err + '. Uploading file ' + params.Key + ' to Bucket ' + params.Bucket + '.');
    throw err
  }
});

return pass;
```

My initial thought was that this was because of the IAM policies, although I hadn't changed anything and it worked previously.

IAM policy:

```js
{
  "Action": [
    "s3:PutObject",
    "s3:PubObjectACL"
  ],
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*"
  ],
  "Effect": "Allow"
}
```

I've been staring at this for the past few hours, but I can't really see what the problem is.  According to [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-with-s3-actions.html) link, it should be the correct way to configure the policies.  And yesterday this worked fine.

edit>
I just tried with "Action" : "*" and I get the same result.

Comment: Apparently this is the culprit:ACL: 'public-read'.  No idea why though, as I grant the s3:PutObjectACL.  As far as I know, this should allow you to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is embarrassing ...

Didn't read the Policy properly, PubObjectACL is not the correct name, PutObjectACL is.